# What is the best way to create an iOS app with the Newsstand layout? CollectionViewController or just a ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create an app that once opened it will have the same layout as the Newsstand app on iOS. I would like for it to have the ability to scroll up and down as the icons stay in their shelves. My question is this : Would it be better for me to do this with the a CollectionViewController or will a simple ViewController do the trick? I ask because I am not too experience with the CollectionViewController if any of you have some experience please chime in, if you have any sample code that would help out as well, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for "the best way to do XYZ" is considered non constructive on Stack Overflow. Please ask specific questions.

Comment: Kind of silly but okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The collection view is designed for exactly this type of thing. [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12) has a pretty good tutorial that shouldn't be too hard to adapt to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, starting that tutorial now..